# Flutter Screen Recorder with Internal system audio

Tags: flutter, screen, record

I am working on a flutter project which needed to record the mobile screen along with the internal system audio. I don't need to record the audio from the mic. need to record the audio from the system instead, like we screen record gameplay in PC. How can I achieve this? thanks in advance.